# Changing to landscape screen in Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a problem in changing the screen to `Landscape` with `expo-screen-orientation`. I have a component that uses `ImageViewer` to show images. When i'm on `Android` it works but when i'm on `iOS` it doesn't. How can i fix that. What i did is i called my 2 function `unlockScreenToDefault` and `lockScreenToPortraitOrientation`:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    unlockScreenToDefault().then();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    lockScreenToPortraitOrientation().then();
  }
```

And inside the 2 functions :

```
const lockScreenToPortraitOrientation = async () => {
  await ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.PORTRAIT);
};

const unlockScreenToDefault = async () => {
  await ScreenOrientation.unlockAsync();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just force it to Landscape

```js
await ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(
 ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.LANDSCAPE
);
```

Comment: Am running an EAS build on a real iPhone and finding this has no effect :(